# .NET assemblies in Mono

Tags: .net, mono

I was looking for Entity Framework support in Mono and found the following page: http://www.mono-project.com/EntityFramework But why can't we just reference .NET assemblies that are needed for EF support to Mono project? What are the general limitations of using .NET assemblies under MONO? COM-objects? WinApi? License?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a lot of .NET libraries that use native Windows API calls for their internals. They just hide those complexities from .NET Developers.

Any portion of those Libraries needs to be ported for use in Mono (including the ones you see listed there...ADO.NET makes heavy use of those calls).

Comment: Agreed, although you can usually still use them with Mono on Windows. That may not be useful but I wanted to be clear that it is a Windows dependency more than a Mono incompatability issue.